# Dynamically adding new UITextView to UIscrollView

Tags: ios, view, uiscrollview, uitextview

I have not used a scroll view in my application and have little experience with its properties. I would like the scroll view to contain a small `UITextView` and when the user taps an add button, it will create a new `UITextView` right underneath the previous one and enter new data there.

```
- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
    if (self) {
        self.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];

        UIScrollView *tempScroll = [UIScrollView new];

        self.logScroll = tempScroll;
        self.logScroll.frame = CGRectMake(0, 120, 320, 390);
        self.logScroll.contentSize= CGSizeMake(320,1280);
        self.logScroll.layer.cornerRadius = 10.0f;
        [self.logScroll showsVerticalScrollIndicator];
        self.logScroll.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
        [self addSubview:tempScroll];

        UIButton *addWorkoutButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeSystem];
        addWorkoutButton.frame = CGRectMake(100, 0, 100, 30);
        [addWorkoutButton setTitle:@"Add Workout" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [addWorkoutButton setTitleColor:[UIColor orangeColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [addWorkoutButton setTitleColor:[UIColor grayColor] forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
        [addWorkoutButton addTarget:self action:@selector(addNewTextViewToLogScroll:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
        [tempScroll addSubview:addWorkoutButton];

        [tempScroll setNeedsDisplay];


    }

    return self;
}

- (void) addNewTextViewToLogScroll:(id)sender {
    UITextField *newField = [[UITextField alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10,20,300,60)];
    newField.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithWhite:0.940 alpha:1.0];

    [logScroll addSubview:newField];
    [logScroll setNeedsDisplay];
}
```

This is what I have so far. Now my problem is getting the new `UITextField` to be added  below the previous `UITextView` on the scrollview. How do I get it to add it below the the previous

Comment: Did you make any attempt to try anything yet? Did you read the docs or do any searching? Your question shows no effort and is too broad.

Comment: Yes, I have added the code I have so far. @rmmaddy

Comment: Increase the `y` value of the new text field's frame.

Answer (score 0):

1.Create your textField

```
UITextField *newField = [[UITextField alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10,10,100,20)];
```

2. Add it to your scroll view

```
[yourScrollView addSubview:newField];
```

3.Refresh the content of your scroll view to show your newly added textField

```
[yourScrollView setNeedsDisplay];
```